# alamofire encoder fails to fetch json

Tags: json, xcode, authentication, alamofire, response

I have a post request using alamofire to login to my site, the request is successfully logging in, but no status is printed in the console, when I try on Postman I got status with some information correctly

```js
        guard let mobile = MobileLbl.text, !mobile.isEmpty else {return }
        guard let pass = PassLbl.text, !pass.isEmpty else {return }
            
         let url = "https://site/apis/loginuser.php"
        
        let parameters = [
            "mob": mobile,
            "pass": pass
        ]
        
        AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default, headers: nil)
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseJSON { response in
                
                switch response.result
                {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                case .success(let value):
                    print(value)
                    
                }
            
        }
```

always I get this response even if the login credentials are wrong! any fix can solve this?

```html
{
    data =     (
    );
    status = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

issue has been solved

```
 AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters,headers: nil)
       .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
       .responseJSON { response in
           
           switch response.result
           {
           case .failure(let error):
            completion(error, false)
               print(error)
           case .success(let value):
               let json = JSON(value)
               
               if let phone = json["data"]["phone"].string {
                   print("Phone: \(phone)")
                completion(nil, true)

               }
```

but I got not response if success!